# Difference betwen MongoDB and DocumentDB With MongoDB Driver

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need a NoSQL database and have been going back and forth between mongodb and documentdb. I am using a lot of azure services so I figured I'd try documentdb and stick to the microsoft ecosystem.

I am not impressed with documentdb. The final straw was when I found I couldn't update a nested object using documentdb. So I'm back to mongodb.

The pricing of mongodb is steep, so I'm considering documentdb with mongodb api.

My question is, is there any difference between mongodb and documentdb using the mongodb driver?

I want all of the features of mongodb with the price of documentdb.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not an appropriate question for SO as it requires opinion to answer, but since you asked... DocumentDB's MongoDB API implements essentially the entire MongoDB API with two notable exceptions: 1) No aggregations, and 2) No ability to install your own code as a secondary and receive oplog events. This latter feature is only used by real-time systems like Meteor and you can using a polling fallback so it's rarely a must-have.

So, if you don't need those features, then DocumentDB with the MongoDB API sounds ideal for your "features of mongodb with the price of documentdb" desires.

True MongoDB performance is highly dependent upon the underlying hardware and configuration but you will see differences in the performance behavior between any MongoDB install and DocumentDB which will be highly dependent upon your design. It would not surprise me if you could build a MongoDB system that out performed DocumentDB for less-than-fully-loaded micro-benchmarks. However, DocumentDB was designed to be essentially infinitely scalable while maintaining SLA guaranteed low latency (10ms for reads, 15ms for writes, both to 99.99p).

Comment: Thanks. Where would you suggest I ask a question like this?

Comment: There is no published list of differences that I know of. Maybe ping the docdb team on twitter to see if they can provide one?